# Make few requests every 5 minutes to external API from C# Web Service without exhausted all sockets

Tags: c#, api, web-services, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I need to send few requests to specific URL every 5 minutes from web service methods. I tried using HttpClient, HttpWebRequest and RestClient, but all sockets are exhausted after hour or two.

Can you suggest me what is the right way to send few requests to some URL every 5 minutes without all sockets to be exhausted? Thank you in advance for any help.

Sample of the code

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public async Task sendReq()
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
    var res = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?  Many of the things you mentioned should work.  Sounds like sockets are being held open when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Use the same `HttpClient` instance for all requests.  
For more info see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: @Zer0 yes, that's the problem. I'm using the code as it is proposed in the documentation, but the sockets aren't closing when the request finish. I tried to set keep-alive to false, to use one HttpClient instance, but I think because this is method in webservice which is calling few times every 5 minutes it creates new instances and doesn't close the existing sockets...

Comment: @stefan I'm using same instance, as it is in the documentation. But, I think because this is method in webservice which is calling few times every 5 minutes it creates new instances

Comment: Understood, but I'd still prefer to look at the code you're using.  Or, if possible, post some code we could run to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @VasilGorgiev please post your code(maybe simplified).

Comment: @Zer0 the simplified sample code is added to the post. I edited the post

Comment: @stefan simplified sample code is added

Comment: How do you check that it are the sockets which get exhausted?

Comment: @VasilGorgiev I have no idea where's the problem, the code looks fine for me.

Comment: @stefan I think that this would work in some App in which the HttpClient is set only once. But, in Web Service on each call to the method (and it is few times every 5 minutes) it creates HttpClient objects and sockets aren't closed. I don't know how to close the sockets when the request finish.

Comment: @GuruStron I checked in the TCP View tool

Comment: @VasilGorgiev you can't close the underlying socket even if you dispose the `HttpClient` instance. The `HttpClient` is instantiated once at app start up since it is static. Please provide more info about your app, for instance .NET runtime, Webframework, ...

Comment: @stefan Target Framework is 4.5.2

Comment: @VasilGorgiev I would try to update the framework to the latest version.

Comment: Hmmmm, you do have the HttpClient as a global variable, I was going to suggest that when I read your title. Your code/logic is much like the one hescribed here: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/. Maybe try this one: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx. Hope it helps.